# In Django, how do I gracefully add a queryset filter to a large group or all members of an object?

Tags: python, django, filter, model, django-queryset

We currently have a media item model with a publish date that determines when the item will show up on our site.  We've been asked to add the ability to specify date ranges where an item is turned on.  If an item has no associated date ranges, its publish date will determine whether or not it shows.  If it has date ranges, then it must both be published and must fall within one of the specified date ranges to appear on the site.

Now the obvious way to do this is to go through and modify every single queryset in our code, adding a filter to exclude items that have date ranges but do not fall within any of them.  But we have a lot of these querysets, and pretty much all of them need to be changed.  So I was wondering if there is some central location where I could add this filter so that it would affect all querysets.

Of course, this would need to be done in such a way that some queries (i.e. the media item list in the admin) would still display all items.  So more what I'm after is a graceful way to affect a large group of querysets with a particular filter without finding every instance in the code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

Something like:

```
class MediaItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MediaItemManager, self).get_queryset().filter(...)
```

You can set that as the default manager on your model like this:

```
class MediaItem(models.Model):
    objects = MediaItemManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

You can ensure this doesn't affect the admin by specifying `get_queryset` on your `ModelAdmin` subclass:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = self.model.all_objects.get_queryset()
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```

This is fairly unfortunate duplication of the base [`get_queryset` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L368), since there's no way to override the admin's manager explicitly. A better alternative would probably be to name your custom manager `filtered_objects`, and use the default manager as `objects`.

Comment: Thanks guys for you help. Really haven't looked into managers much to this point, so this will be a new adventure for me. There is light at the end of the tunnel though!

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly what [custom model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) are for. Define a manager subclass and override `get_query_set` with your query. Then, you'll need to explicitly define a default manager *first*, then call your custom one `objects`, and it should just work.

Note, even though you can do this, I would advise against it. At the very least, call your custom manager something else - eg `restricted` - and do a search and replace across your code to replace references to objects to the custom version. That allows people reading your codeto realise that the query is not the standard one.